# GitLab CI generates database name for Postgres that is longer than the 63 character limit (django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured)

Tags: django, postgresql, gitlab-ci

I'm having trouble using postgres as a service in a GitLab CI job that runs pytest for a Django application.

Here is my GitLab CI job:

```yaml
Pytest:
  image: python:3.8
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgres:13.1
    - redis:6.0.9-alpine
  variables:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "backend.settings.gitlab_ci"
    # the database name is too long, setting here explicitly
    # I tried setting DATABASE_URL and it didn't work:
    # DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres"
    SECRET_KEY: "secret"
    DEBUG: "1"
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  script:
    - cd backend
    - pip install -r requirements/base.txt
    - pip install -r requirements/test.txt
    - flake8
    - black -l 79 -S --diff .
    - pytest --cov --cov-config=.coveragerc
  coverage: '/TOTAL.+ ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}%)/'
```

In `backend/settings/gitlab_ci.py` I have the following `DATABASES` settings:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
}
```

Here are relevant logs from the failing CI job.

```py
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
self = <django.db.backends.postgresql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7f8d71b8de20>
    def get_connection_params(self):
        settings_dict = self.settings_dict
        # None may be used to connect to the default 'postgres' db
        if settings_dict['NAME'] == '':
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
                "Please supply the NAME value.")
        if len(settings_dict['NAME'] or '') > self.ops.max_name_length():
>           raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "The database name '%s' (%d characters) is longer than "
                "PostgreSQL's limit of %d characters. Supply a shorter NAME "
                "in settings.DATABASES." % (
                    settings_dict['NAME'],
                    len(settings_dict['NAME']),
                    self.ops.max_name_length(),
                )
            )
E           django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The database name 'test_/runner-72989761-project-22626407-concurrent-0-a737df6e05b7c794-build-2/postgres' (85 characters) is longer than PostgreSQL's limit of 63 characters. Supply a shorter NAME in settings.DATABASES.
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py:161: ImproperlyConfigured
```

Here are a link to all of the pipelines on GitLab https://gitlab.com/briancaffey/sec-filings-app/-/pipelines.

Here are some things I have tried in order to fix the issue:

- setting the `NAME` value in the `default` for `DATABASES` to `ci`.
- setting `DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres"` in the CI job variables
- Reverting to postgres version 11.5, the version I have used on several other projects in a similar way where the database name length is not an issue.
- Setting the `NAME` to `None` (from the logs: `# None may be used to connect to the default 'postgres' db`)

I think GitLab CI is somehow changing the value of the database name, since it showing up as:

```
test_/runner-72989761-project-22626407-concurrent-0-a737df6e05b7c794-build-2/postgres
```

in the failing CI job logs.

**Edit**: I have this working with the suggestions from @Origin. Here is my new pipeline definition:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

Pytest:
  image: python:3.9
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgres:12.2-alpine
    - redis:6.2.4
  variables:
    # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html#use-postgresql-with-the-docker-executor
    POSTGRES_DB: ci
    POSTGRES_NAME: ci
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
    POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST: "postgres"
    REDIS_SERVICE_HOST: "redis"
    SECRET_KEY: "secret"
    DEBUG: "1"
  before_script:
    - cd backend
    - pip install -r requirements_dev.txt
  script:
    - flake8
    - black -l 79 -S --check .
    - pytest --cov
  after_script:
    - echo "Pytest tests complete"
  coverage: "/TOTAL.+ ([0-9]{1,3}%)/"
```

`POSTGRES_DB` is for the `postgres` service, and `POSTGRES_NAME` is the database name in my Django settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

Also, If you are giving POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
You don't have to use a password.

I think in your case the issue occurs because you haven't set POSTGRES_DB & POSTGRES_USER. In case an explicit dbname is not given I think username is taken as db name and since username is not given runner name is taken.

Also would be better changing the POSTGRES_USER
to something else in case there is some issue with using postgres.